# Showing a line is parallel to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

> How would I show that the line $A=[(x,y,z)=(0,t,t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}]$ is parallel to the plane $5x-3y+3z=1$?

I know the normal vector would be $(5,-3,3)$, but how would I get the the directional of $A$?

Comment: All you need to do is to show that the dot product of the vector representation of Line A with the normal vector of the plane is $0$

Comment: Show that $A$ is orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane. Since you're in 3d it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of $A$ is $(0,1,1)$.  Check if $(0,1,1)$ and $(5,-3,3)$ are perpendicular. Since the dot product is zero,  they are.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that the plane is parallel if its normal is orthogonal to the vector.

Answer (score 1):

A directing vector of the line is $(0,1,1)$since the vector equation of the line is
$$\overrightarrow{OM}=t\,(0,1,1).$$
This directing vector has to be orthogonal to the  normal vector of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation $5x-3y+3z=1$, replace the $x$ by 0, the $y$ by $t$, and the $z$ by $t$.  After replacement, if the left hand side cannot be 1, then you know that the line never touched the plane and therefore the line and the plane are parallel.